# The buffer '' is accessed out of bounds

Tags: c, buffer

During a check with the static code analysis tool cppcheck (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page) the tool discovered a severe error in the code:

```
#define MAX_PICTURE_HISTORY 10

#define PICTURE_INTERLACED_ODD 1
#define PICTURE_INTERLACED_EVEN 2

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char* pData;
    unsigned int Flags;
} TPicture;


typedef struct
{
    TPicture* PictureHistory[MAX_PICTURE_HISTORY];
    unsigned char *Overlay;
    unsigned int OverlayPitch;
    unsigned int LineLength;
    int FrameWidth;
    int FrameHeight;
    int FieldHeight;
    MEMCPY_FUNC* pMemcpy;
    unsigned int InputPitch;
} TDeinterlaceInfo;
```

Code:

```
TPicture Picture[ 8 ];
int stride = (width*2);
int i;

Info.FieldHeight = height / 2;
Info.FrameHeight = height;
Info.FrameWidth = width;
Info.InputPitch = stride*2;
Info.LineLength = stride;
Info.OverlayPitch = outstride;
Info.pMemcpy = fast_memcpy;

Picture[ 0 ].pData = data->f0 + stride;
Picture[ 0 ].Flags = PICTURE_INTERLACED_ODD;

Picture[ 1 ].pData = data->f0;
Picture[ 1 ].Flags = PICTURE_INTERLACED_EVEN;

Picture[ 2 ].pData = data->f1 + stride;
Picture[ 2 ].Flags = PICTURE_INTERLACED_ODD;

Picture[ 3 ].pData = data->f1;
Picture[ 3 ].Flags = PICTURE_INTERLACED_EVEN;

Picture[ 4 ].pData = data->f2 + stride;
Picture[ 4 ].Flags = PICTURE_INTERLACED_ODD;

Picture[ 5 ].pData = data->f2;
Picture[ 5 ].Flags = PICTURE_INTERLACED_EVEN;

for( i = 0; i < MAX_PICTURE_HISTORY; i++ ) {
    Info.PictureHistory[ i ] = &(Picture[ i ]);   /* <-- The buffer Picture is accessed out of bounds */
}
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code above. Any ideas why these get picked up and how fix this?
Best regards.

Comment: Your static analysis tool didn't tell you the value of `i` in the failure case?

Comment: If you got an error message from the tool, please include it in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MAX_PICTURE_HISTORY` is defined as 10 but `Picture` has only 8 elements

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
#define MAX_PICTURE_HISTORY 10
```

and then

```
TPicture Picture[ 8 ];

for( i = 0; i < MAX_PICTURE_HISTORY; i++ ) {
    Info.PictureHistory[ i ] = &(Picture[ i ]);   /* <-- The buffer Picture is accessed out of bounds */
}
```

That's two more elements accessed than provided.

Answer (score 0):

The message is deserved. Your picture array has 8 elements (0..7), while the loop runs to MAX_PICTURE_HISTORY < 10 accessing elements 8 and 9 beyond the array.

The code would be cleaner and guarded from errors like that if you used

```
 TPicture Picture[ MAX_PICTURE_HISTORY ];
```

instead of the hardcoded 8.